# Swift - JSON data wont display in UITableview

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am trying to retrieve data from a server. I can display my data in the console.

I'm trying to display it in a UITableview but nothing happens. 
I tried to create a local JSON file and I am able to display it, but when coming from the server it wont work.

```
let newUrl = URL(string: urlGetNotifications)
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        var session = URLSession.shared
        var request = URLRequest(url: newUrl!)

        session = URLSession(configuration: configuration)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.setValue(authkeyFCM, forHTTPHeaderField: "auth-key")
        request.setValue(tokenFCM.string(forKey: "tokenFCM"), forHTTPHeaderField: "token")

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                guard let j = newUrl
                    else{
                        print("data not found")
                        return
                }

                guard let d = try? Data(contentsOf: j)
                    else { print("failed")
                        return

                }

                guard let rootJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: d, options: [])
                    else{ print("failedh")
                        return

                }
                if let data = data, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {

                    if let JSON = rootJSON as? [String: Any] {

                        print("data: \(dataString)")
                        guard let jsonArray = JSON["data"] as? [[String: Any]] else {
                            return
                        }

                        print(jsonArray)
                        let name = jsonArray[0]["type"] as? String
                        print(name ?? "NA")
                        print(jsonArray.last!["created_at"] as? String as Any)

                        self.notificationList = jsonArray.compactMap{return NotificationData($0)}
                        self.tableView.reloadData()

                    }

                }
            }

        })
        task.resume()
```

Comment: The first two `guard` expressions are pointless. Remove them.If the data is supposed to be JSON use **only** the `NSJSONSerialization` API and **catch** and print the error rather than ignoring the error and printing a meaningless literal string.

Comment: Also you may want to get off the main Queue for the most parts. Only use it when you make async changes to your UI, aka `tableView.reloadData()` makes it easier to read...

Answer (score 0):

create a variable for the URL and create struct contain the all param
in the main add variable of type the struck then start fetch the data

```
var users: [User]() = []

func fetchUsers(using url: String){
    let url = URL(string: url)!
    let _ = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url){ (data,response,error)
        in
        guard let data = data else {return}
        do{
            let userFetch = try JSONDecoder().decode([Post].self, from: data)  // decode * ( Codable )
            self.users = userFetch
            self.load(with: userFetch)
            self.userCollection = userFetch
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        } catch{
            print("error loading data cause: \(error)")
            }
        }.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

This one works

```
 let newUrl = URL(string: urlGetNotifications)
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        var session = URLSession.shared
        var request = URLRequest(url: newUrl!)

        session = URLSession(configuration: configuration)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.setValue(authkeyFCM, forHTTPHeaderField: "auth-key")
        request.setValue(tokenFCM.string(forKey: "tokenFCM"), forHTTPHeaderField: "token")

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
                    //self.showSpinner(onView: self.view)
                    print("The Response is : ",json)

                    if let data = data, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {

                        if let JSON = json as? [String: Any] {

                            print("dumaan ba dito")
                            print("data: \(dataString)")
                            guard let jsonArray = JSON["data"] as? [[String: Any]] else {
                                return
                            }

                            print(jsonArray)
                            let name = jsonArray[0]["type"] as? String
                            print(name ?? "NA")
                            print(jsonArray.last!["created_at"] as? String as Any)

                            self.notificationList = jsonArray.compactMap{return NotificationData($0)}
                            self.tableView.reloadData()

                        }

                    }




                } catch {
                    print("JSON error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }


            } // end

        })
        task.resume()
```

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.